# Why do many DACs have differential output?

Tags: dac

Many DACs like PCM1794 (current output) and PCM1793 (voltage output) have a differential output. What are the benefits from this, other than an easy way to convert its output signal to ground-referenced AC via a differential amplifier.

Comment: For high frequency DACs you can drive a center-tapped transformer.

Comment: Because differential signals are much less sensitive to external disturbances like small voltage differences between grounds. So it is much easier to route the signal to another circuit (which might be on a different ground) while keeping it noise and disturbance free. And if you want a single ended signal anyway, just use one output.

Answer (score 12):

Other pins on the same chip carry logic level signals, which will cause measurable currents into the input impedances of those pins, as well as further switching activity within the DAC.

Those currents will cause voltage drops across the GND bond wires.

If it's a high resolution DAC, (above 16 bits), those voltage drops can be comparable to the analog output signal, and considerably larger than the output signal by the time you reach 20 bits.

Remember that the digital input signals are a million times larger in amplitude, (for a 20 bit ADC), with fast switching edges, and in close proximity to the analog output and ground.

Now separating analog and digital grounds can minimise the pollution on the analog ground, but even so, they will be connected at some point, and without extraordinary care, some coupling between them will occur.

Providing both true and inverted analog outputs is relatively cheap and simple. They both contain this noise, as they are both referenced to the same analog ground. But it is common mode noise, allowing a differential amplifier to eliminate this noise in a location relatively remote from the DAC itself.

Answer (score 8):

Differential signals have a number of advantages:

- A voltage is a always a difference between two signals. For a differential signal the impedance is the same for both outputs as opposed to a single-ended signal where "ground" usually has the lower impedance. For a differential output an interferer would see the same impedance on both outputs and therefore the result would be a common-mode signal that could be rejected.
- A differential signal has twice the signal swing since both outputs can move. This results in four times the signal power with only twice the noise power. This is important for ICs where the supply voltage is often limited by the technology.
- Differential outputs don't produce even order harmonics due to their inherent symmetry.
- Integrated circuits often use a differential structure internally for similar reasons. A differential output is therefore a natural extension of this concept.